# VBA - multy-sheet export (loop issue)

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone look into the attached VBA . Issue is that it exports the first sheet correct , but any sheet after that isn`t exported and returns to the Generate Configs tab, exporting the values. Any suggestion where am I going wrong with the loop ?

```
Sub ExportConfigurations_Click()
    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String
    
    Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
    Dim CurrentFormat As Long
    
    Dim wscount As Integer
    
    wscount = 0
    
    CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
    ' Store current details for the workbook
    
    Dim thepath As String
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    Dim selectedfolder As Variant
    
    
    With fd
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each selectedfolder In .SelectedItems
                'MsgBox "The path is: " & selectedfolder
                SaveToDirectory = selectedfolder & "\"
            Next selectedfolder
            
            'If Len(Dir(SaveToDirectory, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
               ' MkDir SaveToDirectory
           ' End If
    
            For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If WS.Name <> "Data" And WS.Name <> "Values" And WS.Name <> "Template" And WS.Name <> "SiteInfo" And WS.Name <> "Generate Configs" Then
                    wscount = wscount + 1
                    WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlTextWindows
                End If
            Next
            MsgBox wscount & " Files exported"
    
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     
        Else
            MsgBox "Save Cancelled, 0 Files exported"
        End If
        
    End With
End Sub
Function Export(SheetName As String, FilePath As String)
     
    Dim SaveSheet As Worksheet
     
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     
    Set SaveSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
    SaveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FilePath, xlXMLSpreadsheet
    SaveSheet.Name = SheetName
     
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Function
```

Comment: I can't repro, seems to be working fine, I got all my sheets exported as txt files. Though your function `Export` isn't called anywhere in the sub.

Comment: Has any of your worksheets a name that is invalid as filename ? Have you set a breakpoint to the loop and check what is going on? Do you have any sheets in `ThisWorkbook` that matches your `If`-statement?

Comment: There are no sheets in ThisWorkbook that matches the If-statement. All names are less than 10 chars in format xxyyxxxx , where x is a number ). The bahviour is strange none the less and I can not figure out why. If there is a way to attach the excel file , I`d be happy to.